# Problem in using ‍`exercises` and `xepersian` packages at the same time

Tags: exercises, xepersian

I want to type some exercises at the end of a certain chapter in a book. Furthermore, I'm using the `xepersian` package to type the book in Persian. I have got some problems in using the `exercises` package for the typesetting of the exercises. They are:

1. The title of exercises is not typeset in Persian which is (تمرین‌ها)
2. I want to have the number of exercises according to the chapter such as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ...
3. I want to change the `:` symbol into a dot for each exercise.

In the following I attach the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{exercises}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\begin{document}

\chapter{فصل 1}

\begin{exercise}
    محاسبه کند 
    $ 1 + 2 $
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the option `exercisename=...` to set the name of the exercises and you can do `\renewcommand\exercises@formatnumbers[1]{\thechapter.\arabic{#1}}` but the colon is hard-coded into `exercises` I'm afraid. You may try `xsim` as an alternative package… it allows you complete control over the layout.

Comment: Dear @cgnieder, thank you so much for your suggestion. But it did not work out.

Comment: Which suggestion? The option `exercisename`? The redefinition of `\exercises@formatnumbers`? `xsim`? I tested all three before I suggested them to you and all three did what they were supposed to… “did not work out” is not very specific.

Comment: I meant the `\exercises@formatnumbers`

Comment: OK. In which way didn't it work out?

Comment: As usual, I just inserted that line of command before `\begin{document}`. Then I got the error that `Command \exercises undefined. \renewcommand\exercises...`

Comment: You need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`… I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `exercisename=...` to set the name of the exercises and you can do `\renewcommand\exercises@formatnumbers[1]{\thechapter.\arabic{#1}}` ([surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351)) but the colon is hard-coded into exercises I'm afraid:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[exercisename=تمرین‌ها]{exercises}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\exercises@formatnumbers[1]{\thechapter.\arabic{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{فصل 1}

\begin{exercise}
    محاسبه کند 
    $ 1 + 2 $
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may try `xsim` as an alternative package… it allows you complete control over the layout:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xsim}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name = تمرین‌ها ,
  exercise/the-counter = \thechapter.\arabic{exercise}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{فصل 1}

\begin{exercise}
    محاسبه کند 
    $ 1 + 2 $
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find what wanted but I find an appropriate solution. Indeed, I should neglect using of `exercises`  package. I used `\newtheorem{exercise}{تمرین}[chapter]` as a new environment for the exercise section. In the following, you may see the results:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\setdigitfont{Yas}

\newtheorem{exercise}{تمرین}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{فصل 1}

\begin{exercise}
    \label{ex-1}
    محاسبه کند 
    $ 1 + 2 $
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\label{ex-2}
    محاسبه کند 
    $ 2 + 3 $
\end{exercise}

\begin{latin}

I can even refer to them those exercises such 
Ex. \ref{ex-1} and \ref{ex-2}.

\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

In this form, I even can cite a specific exercise.